# VB.NET Throws: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have this error when I created a checkbox and after I run the query it throws me an error and I tried to figure out on how to fix this issue for almost 4 hours but no luck. What I did earlier was I tried to convert it to double (As as the error told me to convert), however no luck, and also trying to convert as string to ("True" or "False") but still no luck. I'm stuck in here. Can someone give an idea how to fix.  I used checkbox for this. and here is my code:

```
If Trim(grdOrderItems.Rows(intGrdTemp).Cells(38).Value.ToString) = "Y" Then
    chbOrdTaxable.Checked = True
Else
    chbOrdTaxable.Checked = False
End If
```

This code throws me an error (Mentioned above).

Comment: How are we supposed to help when you give us, an unrepoducible bug with the code given. "**it** throws me" ; "convert **it** to double". you talk about query and put a sql server tag but the code (and the bug) seems unrelated directly (AFAIK at least). Did you debug step by step to look what is the content of all that intermediate stuff (Rows, Cells, Value etc.) ? (and if yes what are those values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what string.trim does is trimming the string by the specified characters for instance

```
dim string1 as string = "*** Who knows the correct answer!"
string1.trim (" ", "*") ' this will return (Who Knows the correct answer!)
'without the asterisk (*) and the first space ( )
```

so make sure that the parameter you pass to the string.trim is a char in the first place

in your case, i assume the return value is a string and what are you trying to do is getting the first character from the string, so the following will help

```
dim string1 as string = grdOrderItems.Rows(intGrdTemp).Cells(38).Value.ToString
dim char1 as char = string1.substring(0,1) 'this will return the first character only
```

Hope i got you right ! and i could help

Comment: sorry for the long waiting reply.  The result of the datagrid row is only string "Y".  When I change string to char it works like a charm! Thanks!